# Magento Listing Product Attributes on Invoice PDF for Bundle Products

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, pdf

I am listing three product attributes `(mfg_pn, oem_pn, & physical_location)` for each child product of a bundle product by using the following code after line 253 in:

`app\code\local\Mage\Bundle\Model\Sales\Order\Pdf\Items\Abstract.php`

```
           //Custom attributes
       $intProductId = $item->getProductId();
       $arrSpecProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($intProductId);
       $strManufacturerPartNumber = '';
       if(count($arrSpecProduct) && isset($arrSpecProduct['mfg_pn']))
       {
            $strManufacturerPartNumber = "(".$arrSpecProduct['oem_pn'].", ".$arrSpecProduct['mfg_pn'].", ".$arrSpecProduct['physical_location'].")";
       }
        if ($attributes) {
            $result =  sprintf('%d', $attributes['qty']) . ' x ' . $result.' '.$strManufacturerPartNumber;
        }
    }
```

The attributes get listed but I am getting the following error in `system.log` every time we generate a `PDF` invoice. We are running `Magento 1.9.4.3` and `PHP 7.2.22`. What am I doing wrong?

```
2019-10-23T13:36:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable  in /chroot/home/user/domain.com/html/includes/src/Mage_Bundle_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Abstract.php on line 258
```

Answer (score 1):

$arrSpecProduct is not counable. 
Try count($arrSpecProduct->getData())

Comment: It worked, thank you!!!